# Freebase get all Movies by Actor

Tags: freebase

I am trying to que Freebase for an Actors Movies, i managed to get the Films from a Topic Query, but if i try to search for the Movies by ID i found there , i always get  a "null" response

Can someone plz help me here, how can i get an Actors Movies with their MetaData for parsing with title, artwork etc?

Currently i am stuck at here:

```
var que = '[{ "type": "/film/film", "name": null,  "mid":  "/m/02byfd" }]';
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + que + ")"));

    var url2 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=' + json;
    $.getJSON(url2,function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

The ID is the ID i get from the Topic Response at film/actor

thx for help

Comment: To clarify, that MID (/m/02byfd) refers to the actor Freddie Prinz, Jr.  He's pretty unlikely to be a /film/film, not matter how you formulate the query.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're after from your question, but if you simply want Freddie Prinz, Jr.'s films, you can do this:

```
[{
  "id": "/m/02byfd",
  "name": null,
  "/film/actor/film": [{
    "film": null,
    "id": null,
    "character": null
  }]
}]
```

That query will return not only the film name and ID, but his character's name in the film.

Comment: One final question i hope, can you plz show me how to get a Movie Metadata using the returned Query from above? i tried to use the same query e.g. with the movie ID but this returns just crap

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Issues, got the Images from IMDB API raled with Title Search